# Partial keys of union type as key of an object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to use the keys of the union type as key of the object in typescript.

```
type EnumType = 'a1' | 'a2'

const object:{[key in EnumType]: string}= {
 a1: 'test'
}
```

In this case I have to add even a2 as a key in the object. Is there a way to make this optional?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgVwLYBVzQLxQOQEMCM2UAPjrgEzYBQVAxgPZwDOwU9ARgFYS3ABcAbwDaAawggoASzixEqdAF0+UFgCdpAcwC+WAVSgFl2YBBbUtQA)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just add a question mark like this:

```
type EnumType = 'a1' | 'a2'

const object:{[key in EnumType]?: string}= {
 a1: 'test'
}
```

The `object` definition with your current code:

```
const object: {
    a1: string;
    a2: string;
}
```

Becomes:

```
const object: {
    a1?: string | undefined;
    a2?: string | undefined;
}
```

Allowing every key to be optional.

Answer (score 18):

please use [Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

```
type EnumType = "a1" | "a2";

const object: Partial<Record<EnumType, string>> = {
  a1: "test",
};
```

Comment: About an hour ago I had tried something similar to `Record<Partial<EnumType>, string>>` which didnt compile. However as you point out putting `Partial<>` around the outside rather than around the key does. Maybe its me but: 1. I don't find this intuitive or logical (i want the KEY to be partial NOT the entire Record); and 2. the Utility Types documentation page is insufficiently detailed to delineate that this is correct syntax. Frustrating. Thank you for providing the answer @ZOFFY