# Typescript: object key should be partial of union type key

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have a union type:

```ts
export type AddPaymentMachineEvents =
  | { type: 'USER_PRESSES_BACK' }
  | { type: 'SET_USER_ID' }
```

I want to construct an object with keys being of `AddPaymentMachineEvents.type` (USER_PRESSES_BACK, SET_USER_ID), and values being strings.
This object could have all, or a subset of the possible keys in `AddPaymentMachineEvents.type`

So it could be:

```ts
// empty object
const obj = {}

// or only one key
const obj = {
  USER_PRESSES_BACK: 'string1'
}

// or all keys
const obj = {
  USER_PRESSES_BACK: 'string1',
  SET_USER_ID: 'string2',
}
```

So far, I have this, but it only allows the object to have ALL the keys, not a subset:

```ts
const obj: { [key in AddPaymentMachineEvents['type']]: string } = {
  // ...
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: `{ [key in AddPaymentMachineEvents['type']]?: string }` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This post seems to answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64482301/9957187

```ts
type AddPaymentMachineEvents =
  | { type: 'USER_PRESSES_BACK' }
  | { type: 'SET_USER_ID' }

type T = { [key in AddPaymentMachineEvents['type']]?: string }

const obj: T = {} // ok

// also ok
const obj: T = {
  USER_PRESSES_BACK: 'string1'
}

// also ok
const obj: T = {
  USER_PRESSES_BACK: 'string1',
  SET_USER_ID: 'string2',
}
```