# How to specify a single key name from a list of options for an object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to specify a key name for a type from a list of options. It seems that all the options are required as keys using my approach which is not what I want. I need to specify a key name from a list of options, not require all the options to be implemented.

> Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; }' but required in type
> '{ a: number; b: number; }'.

```
type Options = 'a' | 'b';
type Widget = {
  name: string,
  foo: {
    [key in Options]: number
  }
}
const widget: Widget = {
  name: 'foo',
  foo: {
    a: 1,
  }
};
const anotherWidget: Widget = {
  name: 'bar',
  foo: {
    b: 1,
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA5AQxygB9cAjHAbgChRIoB1BAEwHMJgsoBvKqKFPAFsIALihpgAJwQoWAGl5QAZkiRiefPgG0A1hBBQZseMnQBdMSgCug0hEmKAvlWcBjVBKgB3Zm2BjGVnZODX4hUVwVJBwFPij1RT48MQBGWKhnR2p3dA48FCRgAAt7QL8A32DsUIFhMRxSPEkYxXjuRKhSVPTM6j4gA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partial keys of union type as key of an object in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481968/partial-keys-of-union-type-as-key-of-an-object-in-typescript). You should use `foo: Partial<Record<Options, number>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use optional fields:

```
type Widget = {
  name: string,
  foo: { [key in Options]?: number }
}
```

Or `Partial<T>`:

```
type Widget = {
  name: string,
  foo: Partial<Record<Options, number>>
}
```

If you only accept one and only one option, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57576688/188031) for the full picture. This is the simple approach:

```
type OneKey<T extends string, V> = { [T1 in T]: Record<T1, V> }[T]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, is there not a way to enforce only a single choice–both `a` and `b` should not be allowed, only one